# How do I add a new VSFTPD user? (Not working)

Tags: 10.04, server, vsftpd

I am trying to make a new VSFTPD user but there apears to be a lack of documentation explaing how to make a new user + pass and assign them to a specific directory.

Does anyone perhaps know a simple way to doing this?

At the moment I just created a new user and this is my vsftpd.conf file
but I get 530 login authenication error

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/lib/
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
listen_port=201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit /etc/vsftpd.conf

Adjust the following

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES (this is to allow uploading)
```

Now create a system user (useradd ..) and that user will be able to ftp to your server.
check out the vsftpd.conf to make it more secure (chroot, ...)

Comment: I've tried this but I still get 530 login failed

Comment: Reinstalled it and something happened lol... no idea what or how... but it works now :) thanks very much.

Comment: I have this same question, and can't figure it out. What does he mean when he says: Now create a system user (useradd ..) and that user will be able to ftp to your server. check out the vsftpd.conf to make it more secure (chroot, ...) OK, now what the ...blank... does that mean? Can someone explain "how" to do this?